# How do I set the UI language in vim?

Tags: vim, user-interface

I saw [this](http://www.gnegg.ch/2008/09/automatic-language-detection/) on reddit, and it reminded me of one of my vim gripes: It shows the UI in German. I want English. But since my OS is set up in German (the standard at our office), I guess vim is actually trying to be helpful.

What magic incantations must I perform to get vim to switch the UI language? I have tried googling on various occasions, but can't seem to find an answer.

Comment: On my side, language en always gave me an error when I started gVim.  I used language C and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As Ken noted, you want **[the `:language` command](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/mlang.html#:language)**.

Note that putting this in your `.vimrc` or `.gvimrc` won’t help you with the menus in gvim, since their definition is loaded once at startup, very early on, and not re-read again later. So you really do need to set `LC_ALL` (or more specifically `LC_MESSAGES`) in your environment – or on non-Unixoid systems (eg. Windows), you can pass the `--cmd` switch (which executes the given command first thing, as opposed to the `-c` option):

```
gvim --cmd "lang en_US"
```

As I mentioned, you don’t need to use `LC_ALL`, which will forcibly switch all aspects of your computing environment. You can do more nuanced stuff. F.ex., my own locale settings look like this:

```
LANG=en_US.utf8
LC_CTYPE=de_DE.utf8
LC_COLLATE=C
```

This means I get a largely English system, but with German semantics for letters, except that the default sort order is ASCIIbetical (ie. sort by codepoint, not according to language conventions). You could use a different variation; see [`man 7 locale`](http://man.cx/locale%287%29) for more.

Comment: I will have to check this out some more - it is not currently working AFAIR, but will only have access to the machine in question next wednesday. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: did not work for me (vim complained it could not find en_US?!) but @August-Lilleaas solution did work!

Comment: On Windows 7 I had to use `gvim --cmd "lang English_United States"`

Comment: you can also add `language messages en` in your vimrc (note: it should be in the very beginning).

Comment: @hfs Many thanks for your comment. I've added `language English_United States` in my `_vimrc` file and it helped me under VIM 7.4 and Windows 8.

Comment: Answer not clear for Unix user (this answer is the top result).

Answer (score 101):

For reference, in Windows (7) I just deleted the directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim72\lang`. That made it fallback to en_US.

Comment: I changed to lang_ori in case I need it later.

Comment: `\usr\share\vim\vim80\lang` for **MinGW** or **Cygwin** users on Windows helps

Comment: @AugustLilleaas Do you think deleting `lang` folder is safe?

Answer (score 41):

Try this in _vimrc.  It works with my win7.

```
set langmenu=en_US
let $LANG = 'en_US'
source $VIMRUNTIME/delmenu.vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim
```

Comment: Same here, this one worked. I believe the `delmenu - menu` cycle is crucial.

Answer (score 18):

Putting this line of code at the top of my _vimrc file saved my day:

```
set langmenu=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: Actually that's set langmenu=en_US.UTF-8, at least on my gVim 7.2

Comment: Works like a charm, of course as Rytmis says without the colon (:)

Comment: note: this will set the language of the menu, but the messages etc. need the :language set.

Comment: Note that you can make it easier by using `set langmenu=none` instead of specifying the actual (English) language.

Answer (score 11):

This worked for changing vim's menu language

```
set langmenu=en_US.UTF-8  [or just set langmenu=en for short]
```

But

```
language en
```

gave me an error sayng it couldn't set en as a language but this line did the job

```
:let $LANG = 'en'
```

The latter come from the [Vim's docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/mlang.html#:language). I added both lines at the beginning of the _vimrc file. I use a Windows 7 64 computer.

PS: this line changes both language and menus language

```
language messages en
```

In the .vimrc file (or _vimrc file if you are in windows)

Answer (score 7):

Ubuntu 10.10 + VIM 7.2 IMproved. Code below changes language for console vim.
Add it at top of your vim.rc

```
if has('unix')
    language messages C
else
    language messages en
endif
```

Answer (score 6):

Adding this to _vimrc works for me in windows 8:

```
set langmenu=en_US
let $LANG = 'en_US'
```

(note that _vimrc is in the same directory that contains my vim74 dir, thats the _vimrc file that vim reads at startup)

Answer (score 4):

:help language

:language fr_FR.ISO_8859-1

Answer (score 4):

These two lines at the begining of your .vimrc file will do the job:

```
let $LANG = 'en'
set langmenu=none
```

Answer (score 3):

Start vim with a changed locale:

```
LC_ALL=en_GB.utf-8 vim
```

Or export that variable per default in your bashrc/profile.

Answer (score 3):

**Two Vim installations on Windows**

Nothing from here around have helped me until I have realized that I have 2 Vim installed.

1. Git Bash via MinGW (Cygwin, mintty)
2. A separate installation in the Program Files on Windows

---

Next [command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15651286/where-is-vimrc-or-vim-profile-for-githubs-mingw32-shell-on-a-windows-machine/15651421#15651421) will filter you all watched **vimrc**-files and their locations.

```
vim --version | grep vimrc
```

- _vimrc (Windows & CMD)
- .vimrc (Bash for Git)
- vimrc (has different locations for both)

---

**1: Vim on Windows & CMD**

Only renaming (deletion) of the **lang** folder helped me.

You can find it here `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim80\lang`

I tried all config settings listed here around and it was useless.

**2.1: Git Bash through MinGW, Cygwin, mintty**

For Git Bash I added `language messages en_US` at the top of `C:\Program Files\Git\etc\vimrc`

Of course, if you prefer to delete the **lang** folder you can find it here

- `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\share\vim\vim80\lang`
- `C:\Users\User_name_xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\usr\share\vim\vim80\lang` for a local user installation.

**2.2: Tuning only Git's Bash (MinGW64, Cygwin, mintty)**

At the end, for Bash on Windows I have chosen to skip manipulations with **vimrc**

I opened `C:\Program Files\Git\etc\bash.bashrc`
and added the following line

`LANG='en_US'`

or

`LANG=C`

Try to do not use `en_US.UTF-8` because it forces some bash commands to produce weird chars. For example in `find 'xxx_yyy_zzz_aaa.bbbddd'` for a non-existing file.

Comment: The most complete answer. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why all of the above answers did not work for me. I kept getting errors about the locales not existing. Maybe it's a Windows thing. At any rate, my solution was to add this to my vimrc:
let $LANG = 'en'

Ah, I spoke too soon. The menus of gVim are still in Japanese, but the intro screen is in English.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your _vimrc：

```
let $LANG='en_US'
```

Answer (score 1):

I simply disabled the *Native Language Support* when installing gvim
(thus making it a custom installation).

[image: 'Native Language Support' unchecked.]

Tested successfully with gvim82.exe under Windows 7.

Comment: Confirmed. 
Tested successfully with gvim90.exe on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue, but neither one of above solution worked:
https://superuser.com/questions/552504/vim-ui-language-issue/552523

I've resolved it by removing all vim packets and build vim [from sources](ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/unix/vim-7.3.tar.bz2).

Hope it'll help someone.

Answer (score 0):

## If you're on Windows and don't want to be bothered issuing commands

### To prevent the GUI from loading localization files

Just go to `Program Files\Vim\vim80\lang` and put an underscore as a prefix in front of all the files that look like they have something to do with your locale.

### To prevent VIM itself from loading localization files

In the same folder as above, prefix with an underscore the folder named with your country code.

*Note*: Windows 10 will probably ask for Administrator privileges by raising a UAC warning.

**By the way**

This same technique can be applied to a lot of Unix/Linux tools ported on Windows, and generally all software packages where the localization files can readily be accessed. If you rename those to prevent the application from finding them, the fallback language will most probably be English.