# Where is vimrc or vim profile for github's mingw32 shell on a Windows machine?

Tags: git, vim, cygwin, putty, mingw32

Cygwin has a home directory where I can store a .vimrc file to set up syntax highlighting.  I know on linux machines this file is usually in a home directory and that it can be stored globally (although I haven't figure out how the global thing works yet).

I'm windows user (I apologize), so I use different shells for different things, and am not all too sure why syntax highlighting is not working when I launch it from the git bash shell.  It works fine for cygwin and for putty. but not so much for git's mingw32.

Another thing is that when I ssh to a remote server using cygwin, I cannot use Vim, but I can use Vim just fine when I connect using Putty's shell.

Any help on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 46):

Git bash uses MSYSGIT, which comes with its own Vim . One way to look it up -

In your git bash type

```
$ type vim
```

it will tell you which vim executable is used. In my machine it points to

/bin/vim

if you type

`vim --version`, it spits out a lot of environment.

pipe it to a grep, like this

`vim --version | grep vimrc` and this will tell you the location(s) where this instance of vim will look for vimrc.

Comment: Ok... thanks for that info.  It also is using the executable from `/bin/vim`, but the root is not really the root of my windows machine, it's the root of msysgit.  I knew this before, and found a vimrc in the /etc folder which I used to copy to my home directory.  When type in the grep command, it says: system vimrc file: `$VIM\vimrc;` `user vimrc file: $HOME\_vimrc;` `2nd user vimrc file: $VIM\_vimrc`.  All of these files have the same setting that I used for cygwin, but syntax highlighting still isn't working

Comment: For me the file was in `C:\Program Files\Git\etc\vimrc`

Comment: thanks @mihkov , I am using gitBash on windows-10 and vim on gitBash , vimrc is in `C:\Program Files\Git\etc`

Answer (score 1):

for my mingw64 windows 10 installation I found the default .vimrc at ...drum roll please... /etc/skel/.vimrc