# Bash on Windows 10: where is .vimrc?

Tags: git, bash, vim, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Where is .vimrc located when using Bash on Windows?  I'm trying to add settings to make Bash on Windows suitable for vim use and to allow performing git diff/merge, etc. with custom settings, i.e., ignore whitespace.

Comment: Mine is just included in my home folder /home/isaac/.vimrc by default.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use `vim --version | grep vimrc` to find it.

For me its

- System wide file: "/etc/vimrc"
- User file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
- Second user file: "~/.vim/vimrc"

see [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15651286/where-is-vimrc-or-vim-profile-for-githubs-mingw32-shell-on-a-windows-machine)

Comment: Excellent, I didn't realize that the vim --version command provided so much additional info.  One strange thing though: on my machine, there isn't actually a .vimrc file in those locations.  I simply created one after navigating to the directory though, so all looks good now.  Thanks!

Comment: if you use gitBash on windows-10, vimrc will be in `C:\Program Files\Git\etc`

Answer (score 8):

**This will edit your vimrc in the current window**

```
:e $MYVIMRC
```

**This will reload your vimrc after you've saved your changes**

```
:source $MYVIMRC
```

**This will configure two shortcuts that edit and reload your vimrc**

Pressing <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> in normal mode will edit your vimrc in a split window. Pressing <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> will reload vimrc to apply your changes

```
let mapleader="\\"
nnoremap <leader>e :vsplit $MYVIMRC<cr>
nnoremap <leader>s :source $MYVIMRC<cr>
```

**Reference**

- [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way CH7](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/07.html)

Answer (score 1):

just type cd ~ and then you will enter your HOME directary ,and .vimrc is there